# Filter by Id - Exact match or get the default record

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, select, where-clause

Filter the table by exact match if the match is not exist filter by default Id. Consider the following Table:

Table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ProductGroupData]
(
    [Id] TINYINT NOT NULL,
    [Name] NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo_ProductGroupData] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
                    WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
                          IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
                          ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY];

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ProductData]
(
    [Id] INT NOT NULL,
    [GroupId] TINYINT NOT NULL,
    [TypeId] TINYINT NOT NULL,
    [Product] NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo_ProductData] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
                    WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
                          IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
                          ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY];
```

Sample data:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[ProductGroupData] VALUES (1, N'Apple Box');
INSERT INTO [dbo].[ProductGroupData] VALUES (2, N'Orange Box');

INSERT INTO [dbo].[ProductData] VALUES (1, 1, 1, N'Apple #1');
INSERT INTO [dbo].[ProductData] VALUES (2, 1, 3, N'Apple #3');
INSERT INTO [dbo].[ProductData] VALUES (3, 1, 4, N'Apple #4');
INSERT INTO [dbo].[ProductData] VALUES (4, 1, 5, N'Apple #5');

INSERT INTO [dbo].[ProductData] VALUES (5, 2, 1, N'Orange #1');
INSERT INTO [dbo].[ProductData] VALUES (6, 2, 5, N'Orange #5');
```

[image]

The `[TypeId]` rages from 1 to 5 and the default `[TypeId]` is **`1`**; If the match is not exist need to return the result with filter `[TypeId]` is **`1`** in the Same `SELECT` statement. Here I projected the table in the explanatory purpose but in actual scenario I used this logic in `INNER JOIN`

I tried with the following scenarios

Scenario #1:

```
DECLARE @GroupId TINYINT = 1;
DECLARE @DefaultTypeId TINYINT = 1;

DECLARE @TypeId TINYINT = 2;

SELECT PD.* 
FROM [dbo].[ProductGroupData] PGD
INNER JOIN [dbo].[ProductData] PD ON PD.[GroupId] = PGD.[Id]
WHERE PD.[GroupId] = @GroupId 
  AND (PD.[TypeId] = @TypeId OR PD.[TypeId] = @DefaultTypeId);
```

Scenario #2:

```
DECLARE @TypeId TINYINT = 3;
```

This above statement i.e., *Scenario #1* works fine for the missing Id's and the default Id, If I tried the *Scenario #2* SELECT statement it returns two rows:

[image]

The expected result is

[image]

How to perform this in a Single `SELECT` Statement. Please assist.

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: @DaleK - Sure. Henceforth I'll follow and I'll try to update the question in a while.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following query:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
  SELECT ID FROM [dbo].[ProductData] WHERE [GroupId] = @GroupId AND [TypeId] = @TypeId
)
SELECT PD.* 
FROM [dbo].[ProductGroupData] PGD
INNER JOIN [dbo].[ProductData] PD ON PD.[GroupId] = PGD.[Id] 
WHERE 
  (PD.ID IN (SELECT ID FROM CTE))
  OR 
  (NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM CTE) AND PD.[GroupId] = @GroupId AND PD.[TypeId] = @DefaultTypeId)
```

The first filter (exact match) is applied by the CTE. The second filter (default record) is applied by the main query only when CTE returns nothing.

Comment: I'm going to use the said logic in `INNER JOIN` Table WHERE Clause. I hope `CTE` won't work here. I elaborated my question for better understand.

Comment: @B.Balamanigandan There is no problem to use CTE plus INNER JOIN. I will edit the answer...

Comment: Yes please. The main SELECT from the `[dbo].[ProductGroupData]` not from `[dbo].[ProductData]`.

Comment: The `@GroupId` is dynamic in nature and we can't expect the same `[GroupId]` value `1`

Comment: I edited the answer again. Yet I don't see any problem. Please test the query on your actual data to check if it works correctly.